# file creation and acces monitoring app

Tags: filesystems, monitoring

I remember long time ago I had some antivirus on windows which had wile accesses monitor, and could tell you if any process accesses a file.I need to monitor every file in my home folder(or any other) what application does the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, this sounds like a job for [fatrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fatrace.1.html) (which uses the [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) API). Here is some sample output:

```
sh(28980): C /bin/bash
cron(28974): CW /tmp/tmpf807Y78 (deleted)
cron(28974): C /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_unix.so
cron(28974): C /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
cron(28974): C /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_deny.so
```

This tells us, for example, that cron did a close-write on `/tmp/tmpf807Y78`.

If fatrace turns out not to be adequate for your use case, you could
look up alternative clients of the fanotify API.

Answer (score 2):

You should try out `inotifywait`, from the `[inotify-tools][1]` package, if you're using Linux. A command like this:

```
inotifywait -m -r $HOME
```

running in an `xterm` should give you an idea of what's going on. It looks like "what application does the actions" is not available, however.